# Margin change causes multiple divs to be affected

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin

I want my logo image to move up without effecting the wording below it, but both elements are triggered even though they're in different divs, wrapped in a parent div.  I don't get it.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the margins, but when I tried to reverse set the opposite values for the text elements things acted strangely.

[A Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntzhh/1/)

CSS:

```
.full-circle {
display:block;
margin:auto;
margin-top: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 180px;
width: 180px;
border: 2px solid #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 90px;
-webkit-border-radius: 90px;
background:#FDF5E6;
-webkit-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out; 
-moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out; 
-o-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
}

.full-circle:hover{margin-top: 2px;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.full-circle').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    {marginTop: '2'}, 20, 'linear'   
                );//end animate
            },//end function
            function(){
                $(this).stop().animate(
                {marginTop: '15'}, 20, 'linear'
                );//end animate
            }//end function
        );//end hover
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `position: relative` to `.full-circle`, and then animate the `top` property instead of `margin-top`.

```
$('.full-circle').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {top: '-10'}, 20, 'linear'   
        );//end animate
    },//end function
function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {top: '15'}, 20, 'linear'
        );//end animate
    }//end function
);//end hover
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ntzhh/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The text moves up because both items are in the flow, and moving the first will affect the position of the second.

Instead of adjusting the margin on the circle, apply `position:relative;` and then adjust the top property to a negative value to move it up `top:-20px;`  (whatever amount desired).

Adjusting the top, bottom, left, or right properties on a relatively positioned element affects where the element is painted on the screen without affecting how it interacts with its neighbors in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

its simple with CSS

```
.full-circle{margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:15px}

.full-circle:hover{margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:28px}

.logo{overflow:hidden;}
```

This will do without JQuery, using jquery also you can do this, just apply change to margintop and also to the bottom, that will manage the change.

now your `.grey` has filter that is making it create extra margin/padding, so for that

I have done this to avoid that side effect of overflow `.logo{ overflow:hidden}`

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntzhh/4/)

this will do.